# Adobe Air - Self signed certificate

Tags: air, certificate

I need to generate a self signed Adobe Air certificate. How to do that? (I'm using Flash CS5 - AIR 2.0/2.5)
I came across [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f74.html) tutorial - what stands **ADT** for and where do I enter the *command line*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash CS5 will create a certificate for you. Next to the to the box where you enter your certificate, there should be a button labeled "Create". (I have Flash CS4 open, but I don't think they removed the feature in CS5.) That will create a certificate for you.

(Oh, and Flash uses ADT behind the scenes to generate the certificate.)

Comment: How could I miss that? Thanks! Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

[ADT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd6.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f66) is "Air Developer Tool". You enter the command lines at a [command prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt). Make sure the directory that contains the ADT program is in your path or specify the path to it in the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the informations. This is still so confusing for me. Is there nothing like a "generator" for it where I can type in my details and get the self-signed certificate out of it? I'm totally wondering why it's so complex.

Comment: ADT is the generator, you type your details on the command line and you get the certificate out!